# Is there any difference in accessing the elements of HTMLFormElement with just bracket notation versus using the .elements property?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a form, which I obtained a reference to by calling querySelector.

```
let myForm = document.querySelector('#myFrm');
```

If I understand correctly this would return a [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement).

I could then access children input elements inside this form via the bracket notation, either by using the children input's id, name or index.

```
myForm['myInput']; 
myForm[0];
```

But I could also do it like this and obtain the same results.

```
myForm.elements['myInput']; 
myForm.elements[0];
```

What is the difference between using .elements or not?
 As a side question, is there a prefered way of accessing children inside a form element?

Comment: 1) Yes, 2) no difference, 3) no preferred method ... Except, using numbered index of `myForm` might give unexpected results, since all elements (also non-control-elements) in the form are included. Also, dot notation can be used instead of bracket notation, when the name of the control element is known.

Comment: @Teemu Would iterating over a form with .forEach also return non-control elements? If so; what would be a good way of iterating over only the control elements of a form? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Afaik a form itself can't be iterated by `forEach`. Iterating [`form.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) would give you the desired result.